# Looking for a word meaning grooming or preening

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to come up with a name for my red eyed tree frog. She cannot stand to have a speck of bedding on her and is constantly grooming herself. I cannot think of an accurate word to describe her for a name other than diva or princess or some such thing. Is there another word for grooming or preening or obsessive cleaning, or anything that could be used as a female pet name? Thank you

Comment: You could call her Preeny....

Comment: I did think of that lol. Thought it might sound too much like (I know I'm horrible with history) a princes nickname, I think Prinny

Comment: Call her Pristine Christine.

Comment: Maybe [Grimhilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_Queen_%28Disney%29) - the Evil Queen from Snow White who obsessed about her appearance.

Comment: @Christina Rice Nellie Oleson https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22nellie+oleson%22+prissy&hl=fr&biw=374&bih=245&prmd=ivmn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicwM_B4Z3LAhXF2hoKHWnSCj0Q_AUIBigB&dpr=2#hl=fr&tbm=isch&q=%22nellie+oleson%22

Comment: Ok, somebody go propose Name My Pet SE on Area 51 right now!

Comment: If you think of a girl just like her from high-school, what was her name?

Comment: Or [*persnickety*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/persnickety) (*Snickey* for short)?

Comment: Prima donna, the red-eyed tree frog. And you have a choice of diminutives: Prima or Donna.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think this question may be off-topic but I couldn't resist getting in on the tree-frog naming...

I vote for ***"Prissy"*** which is both short for Priscilla and is a personality trait ([per MW-O](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prissy)):

> **Prissy**: "having or showing the annoying attitude of people who care too much about dressing and behaving properly and who are easily upset by other people's behavior, language, etc.",  also "overly prim and precise"

Answer (score 0):

I like the "Prissy" from Kristina. You could also look to play on some variation of "neat freak" (Freaky?), fastidious, princess, dainty, dapper, spiffy, or.... narcissist (your tree frog is a narc!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a word that describes such a tree-frog (or any living thing for that matter) overly concerned with being clean and neat, I like the word *fastidious*.  How you can make that into a pet name I leave to those more qualified than me.